# Steps to reference .NET assemblies like System.Xml.Dll in vc++ win32 console project

Tags: xml, visual-c++

I am trying to reference System.Xml.Dll assembly for XML parsing in c++, as i didn't find an easy and quick way to parse the XML file from vc++ project.

Can someone tell me how to add this dll as a reference to the project and use the same for parsing?

secindly, is the better way of parsing XML from VC++ project apart from using .NET assemblies?

Answer (score 1):

## using directive call

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yab9swk4.aspx

In your project properties under

Configuration Properties -> 
select 
Common Language Runtime Support, Old Syntax (/clr:oldSyntax)

then in your C++ code on top add

## using